# Klein-Gordon quantum relativistic equation negative energy

Tags: energy, charge, klein-gordon-equation

Interpretation of solutions with negative energies was such that charge, rather then probability, density was assumed. When inserting charge of a particle negative sign is then obviously due to charge.  How did the equation know this? Maybe it is a stupid question, but how did the equation know our convention regarding different kinds of charges?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking, but I think you are asking about the "negative probability" problem in QM. In that case, have a look at e.g. [this question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/160230/50583) - the answer is that "relativistic quantum mechanics" is a "hack", and full QFT has no such problem because the equations are for operator-valued fields, not wavefunctions, then.

Comment: Well, negative probabilities are solved by assuming it is actually a charge density. Actually it is assumed that this was an indication of existence of antiparticles.