# Quantization of Klein-Gordon field (what is creation operator there and what annihilation)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, conventions, second-quantization

Recently in my class we studied quantization of fields and I'm brooding over
an argument/ motivation on the construction
of the quantization of the Klein-Gordon field. Recall the "classical"
Klein-Gordon field is a solution of Klein Gordon-equation [Klein Gordon-equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation) and looks like

$$\phi(\vec{x},t) = \int c \cdot d^3p\left[a(\vec{p})\mathrm{e}^{+i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-E_pt)} + b(\vec{p})\mathrm{e}^{-i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-E_pt))}\right] $$

where $c$ is an appropriate normalization constant and $a(\vec{p})$ and $b(\vec{p})$
are coefficients with respect the expansion with respect the eigen vector basis of the hamiltonian.
When we quantize the $a(\vec{p})$ and $b(\vec{p})$ become operators
$\hat{a}(\vec{p})$ and $\hat{b}(\vec{p})$ in

$$\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) = \int c \cdot d^3p\left[\hat{a}(\vec{p})\mathrm{e}^{+i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-E_pt)} + \hat{b}^(\vec{p})\mathrm{e}^{-i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-E_pt))}\right] $$

and in the lecture we called $\hat{a}(\vec{p})$ the "creation" operator and
$\hat{b}(\vec{p})$ the "annihilation" operator. But why not reversed? I not
understand why $\hat{a}(\vec{p})$ is now the creation and
$\hat{b}(\vec{p})$ annihilation. Therefore why the creation corresponds to
exponention with negative sign and annihilation with positive and not vice versa?

As a "reason" or let say a motivation my lecturer explained it as follows:

> If we consider a process with initial state described by wave function $\phi_i e^{-iE_it}$
> and final state described by wave function $\phi_f e^{-iE_ft}$
> and we want to calculate the probability amplitude then when we integrate
> over $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} dt \int d^3 \vec{x}$ the integrand is given by

$$(\phi_f e^{-iE_if})^* \hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) \phi_i e^{-iE_it} =
(\phi_f)^* e^{+iE_if}) \hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) \phi_i e^{-iE_it} $$

> So the exponential of the final state is complex conjugated. This
> "contains" morally the reason why the creation operator corresponds to
> exponention with negative sign and annihilation with positive sign.
> Of course, as the lecturer added that's not a formal proof but a motivation
> why this choice might be "reasonable".

Unfortunately, I was not clever enough to understand why this elementary observation on the integrand I sketched above provides the hint why the creation operator corresponds to
exponention with negative sign and annihilation with positive sign and not in reversed way. I think that the essential ingredient to solve the problem is to understand if $\phi_i e^{-iE_it}$ is arbitrary initial state then what is

$$\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) \phi_i e^{-iE_it}~?$$

Assume that the initial state is $|0\rangle$. What is $\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) |0\rangle$? My hope is $\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) |0\rangle = |\vec{x}\rangle$ since the well known relation between eigen vectors of momentum and place operators gives $\langle p |  |\vec{x} \rangle = e^{-i px}$. So if $\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) |0\rangle = |\vec{x}\rangle$ then indeed we can conlude that $\hat{a}(\vec{p})$ is the creation operator with $\hat{a}(\vec{p}) |0\rangle= |p \rangle$. But for this we need to verify that $\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) |0\rangle = |\vec{x}\rangle$ is true but that's not clear for me.

Does anybody have an idea what my lecturer possibly had in mind making this sketch and how this observation provide a hint/motivation why in
the quantization of Klein-Gordon field the creation and annihilations
operators were chosen in that way and not the reversed way? I have no idea
how this sketch justifies the choice.

In physics.stackexchange I found a couple of questions dealing with similar problems like [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/284213/), [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/412568/) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/413698/). The motivation of my question is primarily to understand why the sketch by my lecturer which I tried to reproduce above gives a "reason" or at least a "hint" that answers my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done the calculation, but you could try to interchange the definition of creation and annilation operators, and check if your equation still satisfies the commutation relation at equal time

$$
\left[\phi(\mathbf{x}),\pi\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)\right]=i\delta^{(3)}\left(\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{x}^{\prime}\right)
$$
which by definition the quantized field should satisfy. My belief is that your calculation will give an extra minus sign.

Notice that, when you have a $\phi(\mathbf{x},t)$, you can get the conjuagte momentum $\pi(\mathbf{x},t)=\dot{\phi}(\mathbf{x},t)$. To check whether the above commutation relation is satisfied, you should remember to take $t=0$ (or any other time), so that $\phi$ and $\pi$ are at the same time. In other words, you should check $[\phi(\mathbf{x},t=0),\pi\left(\mathbf{x}^{\prime},t=0\right)]$

Comment: I should add that, of course, we should also require the creation and annilation operator to satisfy the correct commutation relation with $[a(p),a^{\dagger}(q)]=(2\pi)^3\delta(p-q)$

Answer (score 0):

Since up to now nowbody posted an answer I would like present a heurstical hand wavy
argument which came to me into mind which migth be exactly that one
which my lecturer also intended to use. I would be thankful if somebody
could look through it and tell me if what I'm write now make any sense.

Recall I asked why when we have our quantized KG-field

$$\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) = \int c \cdot d^3p\left[\hat{a}(\vec{p})\mathrm{e}^{+i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-E_pt)} + \hat{b}(\vec{p})\mathrm{e}^{-i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-E_pt))}\right] $$$$

the $\hat{a}(\vec{p})$ corresponds to creation operator and $\hat{b}(\vec{p})$
to annihilation. And the heuristical hint my lecturer gave in the course
was to consider

$$(\phi_f e^{-iE_if})^* \hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) \phi_i e^{-iE_it} =
(\phi_f)^* e^{+iE_if}) \hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) \phi_i e^{-iE_it} $$

How does it help me? Firstly, a general wave function $ |\varphi(t) \rangle$
is given by $e^{-iH_{KG}t}|\varphi(0) \rangle$ , note we have here
minus in exponent. Expanding $ |\varphi(t) \rangle$ in momenta basis
$\{|p \rangle \}$ we obtain $|\varphi(t) \rangle= \sum_p e^{-iH_{KG}t}c(p) |p \rangle
=\sum_p e^{-iE_pt} c(p)|p \rangle$, $E_p >0$.
$E_p >0$ means we consider unly positive energies and therefore
no antiparticles are involved. Note that $c(p)$ not depend on time.

Now it is reasonable require that  $\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) |0\rangle$ is a
wave function in usual sense, that is the exponent in time evolution operator
has negate sign. Therefore by above $\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) |0\rangle=
\sum_p e^{-iE_pt} c(p)|p \rangle$.

Assume $\hat{b}(\vec{p})$ creates and $\hat{b}(\vec{p})$ annihilates. Then
$\hat{a}(\vec{p}) |0 \rangle= |0 \rangle$ and $\hat{b}(\vec{p}) |0 \rangle= |p \rangle$
and thus $\hat{\phi}(\vec{x},t) |0\rangle= 
\sum_p \mathrm{e}^{-i(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}-E_pt))} |p \rangle=
\sum_p e^{+iE_p t} c(p) |p \rangle$. Comparing the time dependent exponents
we obtain a contradiction, therefore $\hat{a}(\vec{p})$ is creation. Doe my argument
make sense?